# Pardot API and custom fields in email templates

Tags: rest-api, email-template, custom-field, pardot

I'm using the Pardot REST API to send emails documented here:

http://developer.pardot.com/kb/api-version-4/emails/#sending-one-to-one-emails

It's all great but I would like to set custom fields in my email template for example like:

{EmailConfirmURL}

And populate them through the REST API, so I could do:

http://email-send-url.com?EmailConfirmURL=myvalue

Is that possible in Pardot?

Comment: are these custom fields in Pardot? or do they specifically passed through API call url?

Answer (score 2):

We are currently building something that does exactly what you are looking to do. Here's what we did.

1. Build an email template that has the HML placeholders that render
   the data you want. In our case, we created 50+ custom fields on the
   Prospect record.
2. Using the Pardot API, update the Prospect Record's attributes to contain the information in your Template
3. Using the Pardot API, send the one-to-one email.

The form handler can work, but if you are looking to rapid-send multiple emails to the same email address, delays may be incurred throwing off the timing.

Another option MAY be to send the complete HTML in the API call, but you would need to test this a bit more to see if you get all of what you are looking for (links rewritten to be tracked etc).

Answer (score 1):

I am also using the same use case but i would say a better approach will be to use a form handler if possible in ur use case to send an email . This way you can easily pass custom fields into Pardot . So create a form handler ,have the same field in it where you want to pass the value and in completion action send an email using this .